# Removing all tabs in a jtabbedpane except index 0

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jtabbedpane

I have a "starter tab" at index 0 of my tabbed pane. The user can create a multitude of tabs and remove them as needed. They can also remove all. However, this removes index 0 as well. What does the function look like that removes all tabs except zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
while (tabbedPane.getTabCount() > 1) {
    tabbedPane.remove(1);
}
```

Comment: Well thanks. I had that exact function with zeros. Brain fart.